# Choose a random image from a folder to add to a subplot | Python

Tags: python, image, plot

I have a folder of several images, and I would like to choose one randomly and add it to a subplot (using offsetbox for example).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice(imgs)` where `imgs` is a list of images in the folder.

First, just specify the absolute path of the folder name:

```
>>> folder = '/Users/path/to/images/'
```

Then, you can get the images with [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
>>> imgs = os.listdir(folder)
>>> imgs
['img1.png', 'img2.jpg', 'otherimage.jpg']
```

Lastly, pick one of these at random and append it to the folder's path:

```
>>> img = os.path.join(folder, random.choice(imgs))
>>> img
'/Users/path/to/images/img1.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in my project:

```
plt.figure(1 , figsize = (15 , 9))
n = 0 
for i in range(49):
    n += 1 
    r = np.random.randint(0 , data.shape[0] , 1)
    plt.subplot(7 , 7 , n)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5 , wspace = 0.5)
    plt.imshow(data[r[0]])
    plt.title('{} : {}'.format('Label1' if labels[r[0]]==1 else 'Label2', labels[r[0]]))
    plt.xticks([]) , plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```